# In 15.04, Ubuntu SDK "make" is failing to build and run Ubuntu Core apps for the desktop.

Tags: compiling, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator, cmake, core-apps

I am getting this error in compile

```
01:09:30: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
Scanning dependencies of target ubuntu-clock-app.desktop
[  1%] Merging translations into ubuntu-clock-app.desktop...
Died at /usr/bin/intltool-merge line 317.
CMakeFiles/ubuntu-clock-app.desktop.dir/build.make:49: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ubuntu-clock-app.desktop' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ubuntu-clock-app.desktop] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ubuntu-clock-app.desktop.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:136: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ubuntu-clock-app.desktop.dir/all' failed
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
01:09:30: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project com.ubuntu.clock (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
01:09:30: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

I can compile and run other projects, however I am not able to do it for the core apps I have tried, including:

```
lp:ubuntu-clock-app
lp:ubuntu-calendar-app
lp:ubuntu-terminal-app
```

How do fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove spaces from all parent directory names.

Comment: How am I supposed to figure this out? How did you know that?

Comment: `Died at /usr/bin/intltool-merge line 317.` On that line the perl script opens a file. What could go wrong? Permissions? No. File does not exist? Why it doesn't exist? File name distorted somehow? Special characters? Maybe spaces.

Comment: I am just flabbergasted.  Brilliant. Thank you so much.

Comment: btw, bug filed https://bugs.launchpad.net/intltool/+bug/1451417